# Issue with Retry in Try Catch Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to perform a ACR to ACR sync using Azure Function and powershell script through http trigger. I have added a retry logic to retry 3 times before the function fails with error. However the retry logic seems to not work as expected. Below is the code, please help

```
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$global:erroractionpreference = 1

$counter = 0
$error.Clear()

do {
    Write-Host "ACR to ACR sync triggered"
    az login --service-principal --username $env:APP_ID --password $env:PASSWORD --tenant $env:TENANT_ID
    Write-Host $Request.Body.action
    $repo = $Request.Body.target.repository | Out-String
    $repo= $repo -replace "\n",""
    $aztag  = $Request.Body.target.tag | Out-String
    $aztag= $aztag -replace "\n",""
    $imageString = "${repo}:${aztag}"
    Write-Host $imageString
    try {
        az acr import --name $env:acr_name --source "$env:promoted_acr_name.azurecr.io/${imageString}" --image "${imageString}" --username $env:PromotedAPPID --password $env:PromotedPassword --force
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Output "Sync failed with error: $ErrorMessage"
        Write-Host "Retrying ACR to ACR sync"
        $counter += 1
        Write-Host "Attempt number: $counter"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
        Continue
    }
    if(!$error){
        Exit
    }
} while ($counter -lt 4)

if($counter -gt 3){
    Write-Host "Sync Failed"
    $StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
}
else {
    Write-Host "imported image from ACR to ACR"
    $StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
}
```

Comment: no obvious Problem what exactly does happen and is not expected ?

Comment: Add `Write-Host "Something"` (I leave the actual message to your choosing) after the `az acr import` line. Whenever it fail, do you see the "something" line being printed ? If so, the `az acr import` command might not be outputting something in the error stream, which mean Powershell wouldn't have anything to catch, even though you added your ErrorPreference to Stop (1). If indeed that is what is happening, you might need to store the output of the `az acr ` line and parse the output, looking for a spefic message and determine whether or not it is a failure.

Comment: remove the `continue` and `exit` statement. Let the `do while` execute.

Comment: @user3732793 the expectation is that, when there is a exception the AZ import command retries 3 times before it fails. But the retry logic is not working as expected, instead it fails after running once.

Comment: as suggested by Hazrelle. And also put the try arround every request..maybe your failure is coming from elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Hazrellel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020462/hazrelle). Posting your Answer to help the other community members.

Below is the code after removing  `Continue` and `Exit` statements.

```perl
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$global:erroractionpreference = 1

$counter = 0
$error.Clear()

do {
    Write-Host "ACR to ACR sync triggered"
    az login --service-principal --username $env:APP_ID --password $env:PASSWORD --tenant $env:TENANT_ID
    Write-Host $Request.Body.action
    $repo = $Request.Body.target.repository | Out-String
    $repo= $repo -replace "\n",""
    $aztag  = $Request.Body.target.tag | Out-String
    $aztag= $aztag -replace "\n",""
    $imageString = "${repo}:${aztag}"
    Write-Host $imageString
    try {
        az acr import --name $env:acr_name --source "$env:promoted_acr_name.azurecr.io/${imageString}" --image "${imageString}" --username $env:PromotedAPPID --password $env:PromotedPassword --force
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Output "Sync failed with error: $ErrorMessage"
        Write-Host "Retrying ACR to ACR sync"
        $counter += 1
        Write-Host "Attempt number: $counter"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
      
    }
    
} while ($counter -lt 4)

if($counter -gt 3){
    Write-Host "Sync Failed"
    $StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
}
else {
    Write-Host "imported image from ACR to ACR"
    $StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
}
```